# Bad aggregate in Sparql request for Wikidata

Tags: sparql

I try to get all the (famous because referenced in wikidata) people alive and their occupation (concatenated), but the query engine [query editor](https://query.wikidata.org/#%23Politiciens%20fr%20nationalit%C3%A9%20fran%C3%A7aise%20vivants%0ASELECT%20%3Fperson%20%3FpersonLabel%20%3FpersonDescription%20%28GROUP_CONCAT%28DISTINCT%20%3FoccupationLabel%3Bseparator%3D%22%2C%20%22%29%20AS%20%3Fpositions%29%0AWHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20%3Fperson%20wdt%3AP106%20%3Foccupation.%0A%20%20%3Fperson%20wdt%3AP27%20wd%3AQ142.%20%0A%20%20FILTER%20NOT%20EXISTS%20%7B%3Fperson%20wdt%3AP570%7Cwdt%3AP509%7Cwdt%3AP20%20%3Fo%7D%0A%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22%5BAUTO_LANGUAGE%5D%2Cfr%22.%20%7D%0A%7D%0AGROUP%20BY%20%3Fperson%0A%23LIMIT%2010) disclaim a "syntax" problem that i can't debugg. Could you help me to re-arrange the request to make it work?

```
SELECT ?person ?personLabel ?personDescription (GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ?occupationLabel;separator=", ") AS ?positions)
WHERE {
  ?person wdt:P106 ?occupation.
  ?person wdt:P27 wd:Q142. 
  FILTER NOT EXISTS {?person wdt:P570|wdt:P509|wdt:P20 ?o}
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],fr". }
}
GROUP BY ?person
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix this, you can add all your non-aggregated variables to the `GROUP BY` clause:

```
SELECT ?person ?personLabel ?personDescription (GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ?occupationLabel;separator=", ") AS ?positions)
WHERE {
  ?person wdt:P106 ?occupation.
  ?person wdt:P27 wd:Q142. 
  FILTER NOT EXISTS {?person wdt:P570|wdt:P509|wdt:P20 ?o}
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],fr". }
}
GROUP BY ?person ?personLabel ?personDescription
```

However, I wasn't able to get that to run without timing out. Using a query hint to turn off the query optimizer and moving this around allowed the query to run:

```
SELECT ?person ?personLabel ?personDescription (GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ?occupationLabel;separator=", ") AS ?positions)
WHERE {
  hint:Query hint:optimizer "None".
  {
    ?person wdt:P27 wd:Q142. 
    FILTER NOT EXISTS {?person wdt:P570|wdt:P509|wdt:P20 ?o}
  }
  ?person wdt:P106 ?occupation.
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],fr". }
}
GROUP BY ?person ?personLabel ?personDescription
```

At this point, we can see that there isn't any data for the `?positions` variable.
That suggests to me that Wikidata's magical population of the `Label` variables (e.g. `?occupationLabel`) might not be working with the aggregation.
Pulling the aggregation out into a new top-level query, and doing the matching in a subquery allows the variables to be assigned correctly, but I still had trouble getting this to not timeout:

```
SELECT ?person ?personLabel ?personDescription (GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ?occupationLabel;separator=", ") AS ?positions) WHERE {
  SELECT ?person ?personLabel ?personDescription ?occupationLabel
  WHERE {
    hint:Query hint:optimizer "None".
    {
      ?person wdt:P27 wd:Q142. 
      FILTER NOT EXISTS {?person wdt:P570|wdt:P509|wdt:P20 ?o}
    }
    ?person wdt:P106 ?occupation.
    SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],fr". }
  }
}
GROUP BY ?person ?personLabel ?personDescription
```

Some careful optimization (or execution in parts) may be required to get this to fully execute. For example, limiting to 1000 (non-deterministic) person-occupation pairs will run without timing out:

```
SELECT ?person ?personLabel ?personDescription (GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ?occupationLabel;separator=", ") AS ?positions) WHERE {
  SELECT ?person ?personLabel ?personDescription ?occupationLabel
  WHERE {
    hint:Query hint:optimizer "None".
    {
      ?person wdt:P27 wd:Q142. 
      FILTER NOT EXISTS {?person wdt:P570|wdt:P509|wdt:P20 ?o}
    }
    ?person wdt:P106 ?occupation.
    SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],fr". }
  }
  LIMIT 1000
}
GROUP BY ?person ?personLabel ?personDescription
```

Comment: Wonderful, very interesting! Strangely the 2nd request give me a time out response. However have you any idea to execute the last request in parts directly with SPARQL ? (i could use Python and a SparkQL wrapper to do it programmatically but i am not sure there is an "offset" in the language to run each part; i could also cut by personLabel name alphabetically).

Comment: You can try adding an `OFFSET` after the `LIMIT`, but be aware that while it may happen to give you good results, using limit/offset without a corresponding `ORDER BY` isn't guaranteed to give you predictable ordering between queries. And adding ordering often causes wikidata to time out. Using python to pull a list of `?person` values and submit them in batches is a good idea. Alternatively, you might try getting all the data without aggregation, and just doing the equivalent of GROUP_CONCAT locally in python.